# Best implementation of the missing unary std::copy

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, c++11, rvalue-reference

C++11 introduces semantics to avoid unnecessarily copying objects, and `std::move` to apply those semantics when otherwise a copy would occur. However, there are now also some cases where a copy is required, but not the default.

Consider this naive implementation of `reverse`, for example. Because range-based `for` uses perfect forwarding, modification to the container within the loop amounts to corruption.

```
auto out_iter = container.rbegin();
for ( auto value : container ) {
    * out_iter ++ = value;
}
```

The goal is to fix this using

```
for ( auto value : copy( container ) ) {
```

It seems simple enough… accept any argument, get the underlying type and return a temporary copy.

Comment: EDSL lambda libraries like Boost.Phoenix usually name this function `val`, as opposed to `ref` (which forwards a reference).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The return type you're computing is better known as `typename std::decay<T>::type`. Other than that, use `std::forward` in the body to reap the full benefits of perfect forwarding:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::decay<T>::type
val(T&& t)
{ return std::forward<T>(t); }
```

Comment: Very nice! The perfect forwarding also has the effect of passing through an rvalue unchanged, so `val( move( x ) )` and `val( X() )` do *not* actually take a copy. This makes this function distinct (and superior) from mine, and deserving of the different name.